# SSL connection with CURL (PHP) working on Linux, same code fails on Windows

Tags: php, windows, curl, ssl, nusoap

I wrote a script that uses our banks WSDL service, using [Nusoap](http://nusoap.sourceforge.net/). Requests are signed with certificate. This script works fine on Ubuntu, Apache 2.2, PHP 5.4.

When trying to achieve same thing on Windows 7 (64-bit, Apache 2.2, PHP 5.4), I get this error thrown by Curl:

```
**SSL read: error:140940E5:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:ssl handshake failure, errno 0**
```

I have disabled firewall and antivirus. I can provide Curl option details, or any other piece of code or info. Thank you!

**SOLUTION:**

curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);

Comment: I have the some problem using nfephp-org lib. The solution for me on linux based server is change ssl protocol: $nfe = new ToolsNFe(); $nfe->setSSLProtocol('SSLv3');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work with a SSL connections you have to enable the `php_openssl.dll` in your **php.ini**

And when you work with curl a common problem is that the openssl module work with a wrong SSL version as default. Most times you should set the SSL version to 3.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
```

I had the same problem before a few days.

Comment: You are awesome. This totally did it. Works also with setting it to 1. Thank you!

Comment: Nice job. Like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nfephp-org lib on an linux based server you may use that code for change ssl protocol:

```
$nfe = new ToolsNFe(MY_CONFIG_PATH);
$nfe->setSSLProtocol('SSLv3');
```

When MY_CONFIG_PATH is the path of you configuration file.

Se você está tentando usar o nfephp-org e está com esse erro em servidores linux, mude o protocolo ssl, como no código acima.